# Full-Text Search with Eve and MongoDB on a field in a collection that's an array?

Tags: python, mongodb, api, full-text-search, eve

I'm trying to implement MongoDB's text index functionality into my app to allow for the user to make text queries in our specific 'names' collection. The 'names' collection has a field 'first_names' which is an array of objects, and each object in the array has a field 'starting_letter'. When I try implementing this into my eve layer with the following:

```
'mongo_indexes' : {
        'text': ([('first_names.starting_letter', 'text')])
 }
```

I don't get any response when making the api request:

```
localhost:5000/api/v1/names?where={"$text": {"$search": "if"}}
```

Also, if possible, how could i add stop words in the eve layer if possible, or would I have to handle this in the frontend of the stack? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create the indexes in mongo shell, verify your queries work correctly in mongo shell, then move on to implementing them in python.